# Eclipse plug-ins in and bundles question

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, bundle

I understand the eclipse plug-in architecture. But I also hear that it consists of bundles. How are these two related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugin and bundle are just synonyms (bundle comes from OSGI, where plugins are usually called bundle, but every Eclipse plugin is an OSGI bundle, thus the two words for the same).